# Jquery remove child and return parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

This one is simple.. I want to remove a child element but return the parent.

In other words, I want to get an element minus the children of a given class..

When I use:

```
 $("#element").clone().find('.elementsToRemove').remove().html();
```

It doesn't return the #element without the children that have the 'elementsToRemove' class, instead it returns the removed elements..

Question is: how can I return the parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use It is because you are using a filtered subset of elements, use [.end()](http://api.jquery.com/end)

```js
var html = $("#element").clone().find('.elementsToRemove').remove().end().html();


$('#log').text(html)
```

```css
#log {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="log"></div>


<div id="element">
  <div>
    <p>something</p>
    <div class="elementsToRemove">elementsToRemove</div>
    <div class="elementsToRemove">elementsToRemove</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>something</p>
    <div class="elementsToRemove">elementsToRemove</div>
    <div class="elementsToRemove">elementsToRemove</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: This will return the inner html of `#element`

Answer (score 1):

Use the [addBack](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/) method.

```
$("#element").clone().find('.elementsToRemove').remove().addBack().html();
```